# Stopping the looped audio in Media Player gives error

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I like to make an Audio looped in my application. The loop is working fine but when the On Destroy method is called to stop the looped audio it gives me an error message saying "Unfortunately the application is stopped working" I have tried giving a stop button also, same error message is coming. This is my code for Media player

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote);
    final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(QuoteActivity.this,R.raw.ohm2);
    mp1.setLooping(true);
    mp1.start();        
    }
```

This is the method I have given in On Destroy

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {       
    super.onDestroy ();{            
        if(mp1.isPlaying())  
            mp1.stop();
            mp1.release(); 
            mp1 = null;
        }

}
```

I have tried searching for a solution for long time, but no use.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining your media player inside your `onCreate(...)` method which means `mp1` isn't valid in the `onDestroy()` method. Also you need to check `mp1` is not `null` before calling `isPlaying()`.

Change your code to have `mp1` as follows (example code)...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote);

        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ohm2);
        mp1.setLooping(true);
        mp1.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy ();
        if(mp1 != null && mp1.isPlaying()) {
            mp1.stop();
            mp1.release(); 
            mp1 = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That I have done already but My loop have stopped working. It just play the audio only once. I want the audio to be played repeatedly!

Comment: Also even though the error comes, the audio stops working in my old code. I want to get rid of the error please! Thanks

Comment: @user1995307 : In your original code you have `setLooping(false)` - it should be `setLooping(true)`

Comment: That I have tried its working fine.Only problem is the error!

Comment: @user1995307 : So post the logcat - if nobody knows what the error is then nobody can help you.

Comment: Thanks Now the error is not coming but the looping is not stopped even after exiting the application. What should do for this?

Comment: @user1995307 : best operation is add logcat result with question to solve current issue quickly

Comment: I have some problem with logcat. When a log cat is added the Eclipse freezes. Thats why I couldn't give the Logcat result this is my error log Timed out while retrieving the attached javadoc for MediaPlayer [in MediaPlayer.class [in android.media [in /home/arise/Downloads/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar]]]

Comment: @user1995307 : Put the code from `onDestroy()` into `onStop()` or into `onPause()`

Comment: I have given the following code but still the audio is not stopping after exit.  public void onDestroy() {
        super.onStop ();